# std::stringstream - string to number working

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am learning C++ and I'm in doubt on how the following code works. My aim is to accept numbers (as a std::string) from the Command Line separated by spaces and separate these numbers from the string. I posted another question related to this and got the program working using the code below. Can you please explain to me how the numbers are actually extracted from the strings?

```
string gradesFullLine;
getline(cin, gradesFullLine);
stringstream gradeStream(gradesFullLine);

for(gradeStream >> grade; gradeStream; gradeStream >> grade) {
    grades.push_back(grade);
}
```

Comment: An input stream is an input stream, it doesn't matter if it's a file input stream, `std::cin` or a string input stream. Reading data is the same for all input streams. So getting a value from your `gradeStream` is no different from getting a value from `std::cin`.

Comment: But if you want to know the *technical* details, then read about [`std::num_get::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get).

Comment: Thanks for the link Jo. I am going through it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to write the loop:

```
while(gradeStream >> grade) {
    grades.push_back(grade);
}
```

Here's how it works:

1. `gradeStream >> grade` invokes `operator>>(std::istream, int)` (or whatever numeric type `grade` is).  This attempts to "extract" a number from the stream, and updates the "stream state" indicating success or failure.
2. The result of the expression `gradeStream >> grade`, i.e. the return value of `operator>>(std::istream, int)`, is `gradeStream` itself.
3. Any standard stream has a method equivalent to `operator bool() const` which lets you use the stream in a boolean context, such as an `if()` or `while()` condition.  This operator returns true if the stream is "good" meaning it has not had any I/O errors (including reading past the end of the stream).
4. So the boolean value is used as the `while` condition, meaning that the loop will be entered so long as `gradeStream` has a "good state" which means `grade` has been populated with a number extracted from the stream (how this extraction happens is defined by your particular system implementation).

Comment: Thank you so much. :) You guys make me want to learn to code.